# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_React$useContext2.signIn') in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

**React Native Version:** 0.63

I get this error:

AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_React$useContext2.signIn')

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1LBi.jpg)

Surely it is a stupid thing, but I just can not understand the error.

Why does it say it is an undefined object? I'm a beginner and I'm just getting started, please bear with me

on screen page **login.js**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
//import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, Image, SafeAreaView, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function SplashScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Signed in!</Text>
      <Button title="Sign out" onPress={signOut} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default function Login({navigation}) {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }

      // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps

      // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
      // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
        // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async data => {
        // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          {state.isLoading ? (
            // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
          ) : state.userToken == null ? (
            // No token found, user isn't signed in
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
              behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
              style={styles.keyboard_login}
            >
              <SafeAreaView style={styles.contenitore_login}>
                <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/logo.png')} />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.campo_login}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={username}
                    onChangeText={setUsername}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    textContentType='emailAddress'
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.campo_login}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                    secureTextEntry
                  />
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cta_login} onPress={() => signIn({ username, password })}>
                    <Text style={styles.testo_cta_login}>Accedi</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </SafeAreaView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          ) : (
            // User is signed in
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  keyboard_login: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  contenitore_login: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7',
  },
  logo: {
    height: 50,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  campo_login: {
    fontFamily: 'nunito-regular',
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: '80%',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: '#9AA5B1',
    color: '#000',
  },
  cta_login: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: '#E26DA0',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  testo_cta_login: {
    fontFamily: 'nunito-bold',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
});
```

Can you tell me what the error is? Thanks

**App.js:**

```
//import * as React from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AsyncStorage, Button, Text, TextInput, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
//import Principale from './screens/app-interna/principale';
import Login from './screens/login';

const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
    'nunito-light': require('./fonts/Nunito-Light.ttf'),
    'nunito-regular': require('./fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf'),
    'nunito-bold': require('./fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf'),
  })

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function SplashScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Signed in!</Text>
      <Button title="Sign out" onPress={signOut} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function SignInScreen() {
  return(
    <Login/>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App({ navigation }) {

  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }

      // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps

      // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
      // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
        // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async data => {
        // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  );

    if(fontsLoaded){
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                        {state.isLoading ? (
                            // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
                            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
                        ) : state.userToken == null ? (
                            // No token found, user isn't signed in
                            <Stack.Screen
                                name="SignIn"
                                component={SignInScreen}
                                options={{
                                    title: 'Sign in',
                                    // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
                                    animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
                                }}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            // User is signed in
                            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                        )}
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    } else {
        return(
            <AppLoading
              startAsync={getFonts}
              onFinish={()=>setFontsLoaded(true)}
              onError={console.warn}
            />
          );
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

For anyone in the same situation as me, I was able to solve it by following this very helpful guide on YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBNm6L7Gb6w